# Wordpress change title with custom dynamic

Tags: templates

I have created a custom php template file, which I use to filter results, based on user choice.
I get the user's choice with the following code

```
$bla=$wp_query->query_vars['something'];
```

So I want to change the wordpress title, instead of the template name inside of wordpress panel, to something like "My template name dynamic- Website name"

I've found this

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'custom_title');
function custom_title($title) {
     return 'Test New Title';
}
```

And it changes the title, however it doesn't show the contents of the $bla.
If you echo it few lines down the code it works. I believe that is because I have to place this filter before the get_header() of the template file.
Any advice?

Comment: you should be able to replace `$wp_query->query_vars['something']` with `get_query_var( 'something' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the check for the query var into your title filter:

```php
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'wpse392764_qv_template_title' );

function wpse392764_qv_template_title( $title ) {
  $foobar = get_query_var( 'foobar' );

  if( empty( $foobar ) )
     return $title;

  return sprintf(
    __( '%s Dynamic - %s', 'wpse392764' ),
    esc_html( $foobar ),
    get_bloginfo( 'name' )
  );
}
```

Comment: It works, however it displays the website name inside of the html at the top row ?

Comment: oops! That should have been `get_bloginfo()` to return the website name instead of printing it. Fixed.